# Refresh control leaving large gap above table view upon pulling down hiding the navigation item

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This happens because of the code below when ios version is more than 11. How do I avoid the same. I have added refresh control to table view. I want to load search bar to nav bar if ios version is more than 11.0

```
    refreshController.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshSelector), for: .valueChanged)
    // Add Refresh Control to Table View
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    tableView.refreshControl = refreshController
} else {
    tableView.addSubview(refreshController)
}


         @objc func refreshSelector()
            {
                if(!searchLoaded)
                {
                    searchLoaded = true

                   //self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
                    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                        self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
                    } else {
                        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
                    }
        //           self.refreshController.endRefreshing()

                  //  tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
                    print( "Got ya")
                    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
                }
                refreshController.endRefreshing()
           // self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)

              //  self.refreshController.removeFromSuperview()


            }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's with the adding of `UIRefreshControl`:

Try this:

```
// Add Refresh Control to Table View
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
} else {
    tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}
```

Try Changing :

```
tableView.addSubview(refreshControl) to 
tableView.backgroundView = refreshControl
```

I too faced the issue and followed this blog :

- https://cocoacasts.com/how-to-add-pull-to-refresh-to-a-table-view-or-collection-view

Comment: that leaves a big between table and the navigation item . any reason?

Comment: That's strange. I am using the same code and it is working totally fine.

Comment: Are you attaching the search bar to the navigation item too? If yes can you help me with the code ?

Comment: Doesn't work, can you share your full code. That might help.

Comment: I am not attaching the search bar to navigation item. It's plain `viewController` with `tableView` as `subview`

Comment: oh, it looks like there is something wrong with attaching search bar to navigation bar.

Comment: @user10264570 Same issue with the spacing and I'm also using a search bar. Adding `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false` removed the weird space for me.